# Object function (a){return new m(a)} has no method 'partial'

Tags: underscore.js, jsfiddle

I am getting the error `Object function (a){return new m(a)} has no method 'partial'` when I try to use the partial example (http://underscorejs.org/#partial) in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/K4c9k/)

```
var add = function(a, b) { return a + b; };
add5 = _.partial(add, 5);
console.log(add5(10)); // prints 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks: I had trouble using Underscore.js from within JS Fiddle. What I did was adding http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js as a separate external resource on the left.

Apart from that, you're missing a `var` declaration before `add5`.

That's probably all as the code itself is correct. See [CoffeeScript version here](http://jsfiddle.net/DmBvj/).

Comment: Yeah adding the cdn fixed it : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/K4c9k/ Funny that _ is defined (which is should not be if underscore was not loading)